# what's the difference between access data in stack and heap?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a struct `Rectangle` :

```
struct Rectangle {
    var width: Float
    var length: Float
}
```

and a globale method:

```
func add(p1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, p2: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>) -> Float {
    return p1.pointee + p2.pointee
}
```

when the `rectangle` instance in stack, it's safe to invoke method `add`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var rectangle = Rectangle(width: 1.0, length: 2.0)
        let perimeter = add(p1: &rectangle.width, p2: &rectangle.length) * 2

    }
}
```

But when the `rectangle` instance in heap, it will crash to invoke method `add`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var rectangle = Rectangle(width: 1.0, length: 2.0)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let perimeter = add(p1: &rectangle.width, p2: &rectangle.length) * 2

    }
}
```

The crash info in below:

```
Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x1038090d0, but modification requires exclusive access
```

Comment: To my knowledge, nothing about where the variables are located is guaranteed in Swift. You can't be sure that the property is in the heap, or that the local variable is in the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing the effects of [SE-0176](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md): Enforce Exclusive Access to Memory, and the [Memory Safety](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/MemorySafety.html) chapter of the Swift Guide. This has nothing to do with stacks or heaps.

The rule is:

> two accesses to the same variable are not allowed to overlap unless both accesses are reads

For the class property and the local variable, you first started doing a write access to `rectangle` (since `Rectangle` has value semantics, accessing `rectangle.width` also counts as accessing `rectangle`) by getting a pointer to it and passing the first argument of `add`. This write access would end when `add` returns, but *before it ends*, you started another write access by getting a pointer to `rectangle.length`.

You might be wondering why "getting pointers to things" are *write* accesses. This is simply because you are getting *mutable* pointers. If you make `add` take immutable pointers (or just regular `Float` parameters) instead, then you will not get this crash.

So now you see how you have overlapping write accesses and that *both* versions of your code is not following this rule. As for the difference between the class property and the local variable, well, exclusive memory access on the class property is checked at runtime as the SE proposal says:

> Class properties and global variables will have to enforce the rule dynamically. The runtime can keep track of what accesses are underway and report any conflicts.

On the other hand, the accesses on the local variable, though it breaks the rule, is actually safe. According to the Swift Guide:

> In practice, most access to the properties of a structure can overlap
> safely. For example, if the variable holly in the example above is
> changed to a local variable instead of a global variable, the compiler
> can prove that overlapping access to stored properties of the
> structure is safe:
>
> ```
> func someFunction() {
>     var oscar = Player(name: "Oscar", health: 10, energy: 10)
>     balance(&oscar.health, &oscar.energy)  // OK
> }
> ```
>
> In the example above, Oscar’s health and energy are passed as the two
> in-out parameters to `balance(_:_:)`. The compiler can prove that
> memory safety is preserved because the two stored properties don’t
> interact in any way.